# Angular: Using Services in Classes

Tags: angular, class, ionic-framework, import

When using a Service in another component you import am as so:

```
constructor(private exampleSrv: ExampleService) {}
```

When using classes the constructor is used to pass information for the initialization of the Object. How can I use the Service in the Class without importing it via the constructor? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You're not really "importing" it with the constructor. You are telling Angular's dependency injection system that you need access to the closest instance of your service. This is simply how dependency injection works in Angular.

It's also worth noting that what you are actually doing, from a Typescript shorthand point of view, is this:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  myService: MyService;

  constructor(serviceArg: MyService) {
    this.myService = serviceArg;
  }
}
```

You are basically saying that your component requires an argument of type `MyService` when it is being built, so Angular's dependency injection provides one.

Comment: Yes but if I want to create an instance of that class I have to give it that service. When doing this you can not use EventEmmiter with other services and components. So how can I use the Service without having to add it to the constructer?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
import { YourService} from 'where ever it lives';


private yourservice : YourService;

initaliseService() {
  const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([YourService]);
  this.yourservice = injector.get(YourService);
}
```

this.initaliseService()
then access via this.yourservice.

if the service you want to use can happily be used NOT as a singleton and it doesn't have any dependencies you can use it via

```
this.yourservice  = new Yourservice();
```

Comment: I´m using an EventEmitter in the service and I can´t access it. So I guess this approach doesn´t fit my problem.

Comment: the event emitters are picked up in the template